# Creating a Facebook session for getting page info

Tags: facebook, facebooker

I am trying to get info on a page that my user is admin for.  This user has granted my fb_connect app offline access.  I have saved the session_key that allows offline access (it has the user's id in it).  I am able to publish to this fan page with this session key.  But when I try to access the page's info I get an SessionExpired error.  This doesn't make sense.  Look at the code and output below:

p is is a 'profile' object that holds the three pieces of relevant fb data (user_id, session_key and page id)

```
>> fb_session = Facebooker::Session.create
=> #
>> fb_session.secure_with!(p.fb_session_key, p.fb_user_id, 0)
=> nil
>> fb_session.user.has_permission?("offline_access")
=> true
>> fb_session.user.has_permission?("publish_stream")
=> true
>> fb_session.user.has_permission?("read_stream")
=> true
>> pages = fb_session.fql_query("select fan_count from page where page_id = #{p.fb_page_id}")
Facebooker::Session::SessionExpired: Session key invalid or no longer valid
    ...
>> pages = fb_session.pages(:fields => {:page_ids => p.fb_page_id})
Facebooker::Session::SessionExpired: Session key invalid or no longer valid
    ...
>> pages = Facebooker::Session.create.fql_query("select fan_count from page where page_id = #{p.fb_page_id}")
=> [#]
```

Perhaps I'm not creating the session right or maybe offline access doesn't give me access to the user's page even though I have permissions to push to it.  As you can see when I just use an anon session I'm able to get the fan count, which I'm guessing is publicly available.  Does anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for `manage_pages` permission and then query the `me/accounts` graph object to get the list of pages (aka accounts) that user manages.  Once you have a list of those pages, then you can get each page's information using the page id.